# How to handle thread-safe callback registration and execution in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns, c++11

For example I've an `EventGenerator` class that call `IEventHandler::onEvent` for all registered event handlers:

```
class IEventHandler {
public: virtual void onEvent(...) = 0;
};


class EventGenerator {
private: 
   std::vector<IEventHandler*> _handlers;
   std::mutex _mutex; // [1]
public:
   void AddHandler(IEventHandler* handler) {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(_mutex); // [2]
      _handlers.push_back(handler);
   }
   void RemoveHanler(IEventHandler* handler) {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(_mutex); // [3]
      // remove from "_handlers"
   }
private:
   void threadMainTask() {

      while(true) {

         // Do some work ...

         // Post event to all registered handlers
         {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(_mutex); // [4]
            for(auto& h : _handlers) { h->onEvent(...); )
         }

         // Do some work ...

      }
    }
```

The code should be thread safe in the following manner:

- **one** thread is executing the `EventGenerator::threadMainTask`
- **many** threads might access `EventGenerator::AddHandler` and `EventGenerator::RemoveHandler` APIs.

To support this, I have the following synchonization (see comment in the code):

- `[1]` is the mutex that protects the vector `_handlers` from multiple thread access.
- `[2]` and `[3]` are protect adding or removing handlers simultaneously.
- `[4]` is preventing from changing the vector while the main thread is posting events.

This code works until... If for some reason, during the execution of `IEventHandler::onEvent(...)` the code is trying to call `EventManager::RemoveHandler` or `EventManager::AddHandler`. The result is runtime exception.

**What is the best approach to handle registration of the event handlers and executing the event handler callback in the thread safe manner?**

**>> UPDATE <<**

So based on the inputs, I've updated to the following design:

```
class IEventHandler {
public: virtual void onEvent(...) = 0;
};

class EventDelegate {
private: 
   IEventHandler* _handler;
   std::atomic<bool> _cancelled;
public:
   EventDelegate(IEventHandler* h) : _handler(h), _cancelled(false) {};
   void Cancel() { _cancelled = true; }
   void Invoke(...) { if (!_cancelled) _handler->onEvent(...); }
}

class EventGenerator {
private: 
   std::vector<std::shared_ptr<EventDelegate>> _handlers;
   std::mutex _mutex;
public:
   void AddHandler(std::shared_ptr<EventDelegate> handler) {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(_mutex);
      _handlers.push_back(handler);
   }
   void RemoveHanler(std::shared_ptr<EventDelegate> handler) {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(_mutex);
      // remove from "_handlers"
   }
private:
   void threadMainTask() {

      while(true) {

         // Do some work ...

         std::vector<std::shared_ptr<EventDelegate>> handlers_copy;

         {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(_mutex);
            handlers_copy = _handlers;
         }

         for(auto& h : handlers_copy) { h->Invoke(...); )

         // Do some work ...

      }
    }
```

As you can see, there is additional class `EventDelegate` that have two purposes:

1. hold the event callback
2. enable to cancel the callback

In the `threadMainTask`, I'm using a local copy of the `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<EventDelegate>>` and I'm releasing the lock before invoking the callbacks. This approach solves an issue when during the `IEventHandler::onEvent(...)` the `EventGenerator::{AddHandler,RemoveHanler}` is called.

**Any thoughts about the new design?**

Comment: What kind of runtime exception? You are not trying to add/remove a handler from *within a handler* are you?

Comment: In my experience the callback/signal system does not offer the right granularity for synchronization. What if the event happens only once, and you have one firing up concurrently to a callback registration? The callback will never be called, and the only reliable way to check for that is to synchronize before or after `{Add|Remove}Handler`. Say, a button widget wants to listen for "resize" events of its parent window; the button concurrently registers a callback, while the window is racing to generate a resize event (e.g. starting maximized); the button might never see the event.

Comment: @ComicSansMS The kind of exception is not relevant, and yes, of course it is due to call within a handler. I'm not trying to understand why I'm getting the exception, I'm trying to find a proper solution without restricting the code of the 'IEventHandler::onEvent'...

Comment: @DanielKO I understand your concern, but in my system this is not a problem. If callback registration will miss events that happened prior to registration, I can leave with that.

Comment: "void main" as a member function? Hm..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Seriously? What are you compiling this page in your browser?? This is just a design question... Anyway, I will update it just for you.

Comment: I have one question though! What if an object of `IEventHandler` is destructed after making a copy of `_handlers` and before calling it's callback?

Comment: This code could use a self-contained example. Yes, often we will take your code as it is, stick it into an IDE (whether online or not shouldn't matter), and try things. Are you seriously surprised that people take your question seriously and want to run it?? Do you want us not to take it seriously enough to run? When the question can't be compiled without extra work, it makes at least me less likely to bother.There are many preferred development flows - everyone has their own. I like prototyping a lot. It's the equivalent of a breadboard electronic circuit prototype. YMMV, this is my POV only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy-on-Write vector implemented on atomic swap of shared_ptr's (in assumptions callback registration is occurring far less frequently than events the callbacks are notified about):

```
using callback_t = std::shared_ptr<std::function<void(event_t const&)> >;
using callbacks_t = std::shared_ptr<std::vector<callback_t> >;
callbacks_t callbacks_;
mutex_t mutex_; // a mutex of your choice

void register(callback_t cb)
{
    // the mutex is to serialize concurrent callbacks registrations
    // this is not always necessary, as depending on the application
    // architecture, single writer may be enforced by design
    scoped_lock lock(mutex_);

    auto callbacks = atomic_load(&callbacks_);

    auto new_callbacks = std::make_shared< std::vector<callback_t> >();
    new_callbacks->reserve(callbacks->size() + 1);
    *new_callbacks = callbacks;
    new_callbacks->push_back(std::move(cb));

    atomic_store(&callbacks_, new_callbacks);
}

void invoke(event_t const& evt)
{
    auto callbacks = atomic_load(&callbacks_);

    // many people wrap each callback invocation into a try-catch
    // and de-register on exception
    for(auto& cb: *callbacks) (*cb)(evt); 
}
```

Specifically on the subject of asynchronous behavior when callback is executed while being de-registered, well here the best approach to take is remember of the [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle.

The callback should not be able to die until it has been executed. This is achieved via another classic trick called "extra level of indirection". Namely, instead of registering user provided callback one would wrap it to something like the below and callback de-registration apart from updating the vector will call the below defined `discharge()` method on the callback wrapper and will even notify the caller of de-registration method of whether the callback execution finished successfully.

```
template <class CB> struct cb_wrapper
{
    mutable std::atomic<bool> done_;
    CB cb_;
    cb_wrapper(CB&& cb): cb(std::move(cb_)) {}

    bool discharge()
    {
        bool not_done = false;
        return done_.compare_exchange_strong(not_done, true);
    }

    void operator()(event_t const&)
    {
        if (discharge())
        {
            cb();
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: @bobah You're missing an important part: How do you synchronize callback removal with concurrent execution of `invoke`? Imagine a callback implemented as a member function of object `foo`. Now a thread calls `RemoveHandler` for that callback, while another thread is looping on `invoke`. When is it safe for the remover thread to delete `foo`? Lifetime issues like this make the copy on write approach difficult to use in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a right thing here. From your update I can see a problem: you are not synchronizing the invoke method with callback removal. There's an atomic but it's not enough. Example: just after this line of code:

```
if (!_cancelled)
```

Another thread calls the remove method. What can happen is that the `onEvent()` is called anyway, even if the removed method has removed the callback from the list and returned the result, there's nothing to keep synchronized this execution flow. Same problem for the answer of @bobah.